# Helm: override values from dependency chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm using a chart it's using other chart as dependency.

Its `chart.yaml` file is:

```yaml
annotations:
  category: Infrastructure
apiVersion: v2
appVersion: 3.7.0
dependencies:
  - name: common
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    tags:
      - bitnami-common
    version: 1.x.x
...
```

It's using this dependecy into its templates like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  ...
  labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
    app.kubernetes.io/component: zookeeper
    {{- if .Values.commonLabels }}
    {{- include "common.tplvalues.render" ( dict "value" .Values.commonLabels "context" $ ) | nindent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
...
```

As you can see it's using:

```
labels: {{- include "common.labels.standard" . | nindent 4 }}
```

How can I override those values inherited from `common`.

Answer (score 0):

The [Bitnami Common Library Chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/common) is a [library chart](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/library_charts/): it doesn't provide any Kubernetes resources of its own, just a library of template functions you can call (with `include` or `template`).  That also means it doesn't have its own set of values in the way Helm dependency charts normally do; it uses whatever `.Values` are in the object you pass to the template.

The [implementation of `common.labels.standard`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/blob/master/bitnami/common/templates/_labels.tpl) is pretty straightforward; it provides a set of [standard labels](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/labels/#standard-labels) that almost every chart should have.  You don't usually need to edit these, and you can't change their outputs without copying and pasting the template contents.

Note that one consequence of this is that, if you have a parent chart and a subchart that both `include "common.labels.standard" .`, they will get different values.  `.Release.Name` will be the same for both, but `.Chart.Name` will depend on the specific chart being installed (parent or dependency), and in the subchart, `.Values` will be narrowed to that subchart's settings in the top-level values.

If you need to *add* labels, this change is easy, and you demonstrate it above.  Helm's general operation is to run the template engine naïvely to produce a text document, then hope it's a valid YAML file.  If you want additional labels, just include them in the template.

```yaml
metadata:
  labels:
{{-/* the generated labels from the Common chart */}}
{{- include "common.labels.standard" . | indent 4 }}
{{-/* and then any additional labels (correctly indented) */}}
    example.com/additional-label: is-present
```